# Azure Devops No such file or directory

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml

I am trying to reference a test dll for signatures in azure devops however I am getting a no such file or directory error. I believe I am referencing it correctly as I can read the dockerfile just fine.

Error:  "/home/vsts/work/1/s/Myfolder/TestAssembly.dll": No such file or directory

Yaml

```
variables: 
    dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Myfolder/Dockerfile-SignedAssembly'
    testAssemblyPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Myfolder/TestAssembly.dll'

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: CodeSign
  inputs:
    script: |
      '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x86\signtool" sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com 
          /fd sha256 /td sha256 /sm /sha1 "$(Cert.secureFilePath)" 
          /d "My Project description"
            $(testAssemblyPath)'
```

Comment: so probably something wrong in the path... you can debug it with adding a prints of `dir` inside your script.

Answer (score 1):

From your pipeline definition, if you don't have any other steps, then the structure of your repo must be like this:

[image]

And as Shayki said, you can use dir to list files:

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- script: |
    cd Myfolder
    dir
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

If your command can't find the file, then the issue is expected.

If you build the projects in the pipeline, the path should be like this(For example, if you are based on .NetCore 3.1):

```
testprojectname\bin\Debug\.netcoreapp,version=v3.1\testprojectname.dll
```

For what is the specific path, you can refer to the situation on local.

Let me know if you have more concerns.

Comment: Thank you for this script. When running the dir command, it is able to find the file. Is there a way to test specifically /home/vsts/work/1/s/Myfolder/TestAssembly.dll